# Parsing a (RNS) polynomial with regex

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to write a Regex to parse a polynomial in RNS (residue number system) form:

```
RNS Polynomial ([Modulus(68719403009), Modulus(68719230977), Modulus(137438822401)]): (67699591241,42814670386,92925202514)x^0 + (42539574637,55054036653,135659663247)x^1 + (52858091297,11618896202,6855552742)x^2 + (45970532823,20845087073,91272562929)x^3 + (11148839321,55275439733,5401722690)x^4 + (31959765643,40620395732,93052536121)x^5 + (57030732406,66026147059,6304524013)x^6 + (27778918692,11276356856,61606736382)x^7
```

I wrote:

```
\(\[(Modulus\(\d+\)(,*)\s*)+\]\):(\s*\((\d*,*)+\)x\^\d\s*\+*)+
```

but I'm only able to parse it entirely. I cannot have a group for the `Modulus`, neither the coefficients `(a,b,c,...)x^n`. What is wrong?

Here's the regex101: https://regex101.com/r/itBQHJ/1

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Comment: @Thefourthbird java

Comment: @HFZ no they could be of any length

Comment: @Thefourthbird I feel like this is not the right solution as I would need to parse the Modulus and also (a,b,c,...)x^n again

Comment: so you could not assign tag name for each by simple regex. are you using java?

Comment: @HFZ yes, Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern has superfluous capture groups, and repeats 2 capture groups which will capture the value of the last iteration.

Also this `\+*` and `,*` will allow trailing plus signs and comma's.

---

One option to is to match the data format of the example string using 2 capture groups and an unrolled form of the pattern, optionally repeating the same pattern preceding with `,` or `+` to prevent allowing trailing `+` and `,`

In the code, you can check for the group 1 and group 2 value and use split to get the separate parts.

The pattern is slightly longer

```
\(\[(Modulus\(\d+\)(?:\s*,\s*Modulus\(\d+\))*)\]\):(\(\d+(?:,\d+)*\)x\^\d+(?:\s*\+\s*\(\d+(?:,\d+)*\)x\^\d+)*)
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6gwzLP/1) or a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/7Xi85D)

An example in Java

```
String regex = "\\(\\[(Modulus\\(\\d+\\)(?:\\s*,\\s*Modulus\\(\\d+\\))*)\\]\\):(\\(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*\\)x\\^\\d+(?:\\s*\\+\\s*\\(\\d+(?:,\\d+)*\\)x\\^\\d+)*)";
String string = "RNS Polynomial ([Modulus(68719403009), Modulus(68719230977), Modulus(137438822401)]):(67699591241,42814670386,92925202514)x^0 + (42539574637,55054036653,135659663247)x^1 + (52858091297,11618896202,6855552742)x^2 + (45970532823,20845087073,91272562929)x^3 + (11148839321,55275439733,5401722690)x^4 + (31959765643,40620395732,93052536121)x^5 + (57030732406,66026147059,6304524013)x^6 + (27778918692,11276356856,61606736382)x^7\n";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    if (matcher.group(1) != null) {
        for (String elm1 : matcher.group(1).split(",\\s*"))
            System.out.println(elm1);
    }
    if (matcher.group(2) != null) {
        for (String elm2 : matcher.group(2).split("\\s*\\+\\s*"))
            System.out.println(elm2);
    }
}
```

Output

```
Modulus(68719403009)
Modulus(68719230977)
Modulus(137438822401)
(67699591241,42814670386,92925202514)x^0
(42539574637,55054036653,135659663247)x^1
(52858091297,11618896202,6855552742)x^2
(45970532823,20845087073,91272562929)x^3
(11148839321,55275439733,5401722690)x^4
(31959765643,40620395732,93052536121)x^5
(57030732406,66026147059,6304524013)x^6
(27778918692,11276356856,61606736382)x^7
```

Another pattern could be using an alternation `|` to match both specific parts of the string, but it will not validate the whole data structure.

```
\b(Modulus\(\d+\))|(\(\d+(?:,\d+)*\)x\^\d+)\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uxFeS6/1)

Comment: but then I have to write another match for the individual `Modulus(...)` and `(,,,)x^n` so I can parse their contents? Isn't there a way of doing everything in one go?

Comment: @Rafaelo In this case yes, but you know that the format of the data is right. Then you can use string functions and split, or use another pattern to get the capture group values like https://regex101.com/r/tv8wxC/1